# MIDINetworkConnection EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, midi

I am working on an app that controls daw software. Occasionally I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors. I believe it is related to the MIDINetworkConnection, even though the project is ARC enabled. It appears to be trying to access the number of connections, but going to the wrong memory address. Can anyone spot the problem?

```
- (NSString*) describeConnections {

    NSMutableArray* connections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[[MIDINetworkSession     defaultSession] connections] count]];
    for (MIDINetworkConnection* connection in [[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession] connections]) {
        [connections addObject:[[connection host] name]];
    }
    if ([connections count] > 0) {
        return [connections componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    }
    else{
        return @"(Not connected)";

    }

}
```

The breakpoint error stops on

```
 NSMutableArray* connections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[[MIDINetworkSession     defaultSession] connections] count]];
```

with the message: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x2033b00c)

In the debugger I'm seeing connections = (NSMutableArray*)0x839ab1e0 which doesn't match the above error.  Could this be the cause of the problem?

This the thread stacktrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x9f2b0, 0x01da9e15 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 21, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5302f2fb)
frame #0: 0x01da9e15 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 21
* frame #1: 0x0000d14b Fader`-[MIDIController describeConnections](self=0x7c3c35b0, _cmd=0x00083ee3) + 683 at MIDIController.m:149
frame #2: 0x00049073 Fader`-[MainViewController internalReloadConnections:](self=0x7d0f6000, _cmd=0x000849f0, sender=0x7d0f6000) + 115 at MainViewController.m:1087
frame #3: 0x000494e0 Fader`-[MainViewController updateDisplay](self=0x7d0f6000, _cmd=0x000847c9) + 272 at MainViewController.m:1143
frame #4: 0x014e2119 Foundation`__NSFireTimer + 97
frame #5: 0x020bf8d6 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
frame #6: 0x020bf25d CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1309
frame #7: 0x0207e6ba CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2090
frame #8: 0x0207dbcb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
frame #9: 0x0207d9fb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #10: 0x038d324f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #11: 0x038d308c GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #12: 0x002b58b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
frame #13: 0x0000b06c Fader`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfff63f0) + 76 at main.m:14
frame #14: 0x02a6bac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Any message in the debug console when you hit the breakpoint?  (Or if you turn off the breakpoint?)

Comment: No message just (lldb)  in the console

Comment: Type 'bt' at the (lldb) prompt to get a stack trace.  It might have clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps the [[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession] connections] collection is being altered while you are enumerating it? (a midi connection is made/drops out)

it is not wise to fast enumerate a mutable collection, especially one that you do not own. I suggest copying it into an NSArray at the start and enumerating that instead

ie

```
    - (NSString*) describeConnections {

       // NSArray *tempConnections = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession] connections] ]; 
      //edit. replaced with line below, we are working with a set, not an array, see comments below..
        NSArray *tempConnections = [[[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession] connections]allItems];

        NSMutableArray* connections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[tempConnections count]];
        for (MIDINetworkConnection* connection in tempConnections) {
            [connections addObject:[[connection host] name]];
        }
        if ([connections count] > 0) {
            return [connections componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
        }
        else{
            return @"(Not connected)";

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Jef thanks so much for the reply! You are probably correct about this, makes sense. When I try to use the code example you provided, I get the warning " Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSSet *' to parameter of type 'NSArray *'  Any idea why?

Comment: perhaps [[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession] connections] is a NSSet or NSMutableSet where I had assumed it was an array. try changing the first line to NSArray *tempConnections = [[[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession] connections]allItems];